# Can I deploy an asp.net web forms application to a Windows 7 laptop computer?

Tags: asp.net

I've created a small application for internal use with asp.net web forms.  I don't have a server to deploy it, but would like others in the office to have intranet access. Just a handful of people will have access (2-6).  It is not a public-facing application.

I saw the following instructions on this site to deploy an asp.net mvc application to a desktop computer-using IIS 7.

1.Install IIS from the standard windows components.
2.Put your code in the root directory of the default created web site.
3.Be sure the firewall is allowed the 80th port.

Would the procedure be the same for my asp.net web forms application--or is there something inherently different (between web forms and mvc) that makes this impossible?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The instructions would stay more or less the same. The process can be a little more complicated than what you've described in the steps above, but it's a good starting point.

In addition to making sure port 80 is open, you'll probably need to assign an IP address for the site too. See the illustration below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should work exactly the same.

One thing you'll need to check is that the ASP.NET framework version the default web site created by IIS7 is using is the same as the version your code was created in. To do this; goto IIS -> Application Pools -> DefaultAppPool then check the .Net Framework version.

Bar that; as long as the physical path of the Site inside IIS is pointing to the correct folder it will work the same as MVC would